# How to create onclick event in .cs file for html <Input> Tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**How to create onclick event in `.cs` file for asp.net c# for html  Tag ?**

Example :-

```
< input type="button" id="btnBeforeOk" value="Ok" name="btnBeforeOk" style="width: 90%;" />
```

I want to create an event in `.cs` file how we can do this ?

### OR

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch("nikunj@yahoo.com", @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|asia|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel)\b)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The above bool isEmail i want to in `.aspx` page ?

Comment: Just add [ runat="server" ] at your html control and then add any  events.

Comment: You can do an AJAX call `onclientclick` to your server method.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnBeforeOk" value="Ok" runat="server"  name="btnBeforeOk" style="width: 90%;" />
```

Now go to HTML view of your page and double click on your button, it will generate event for you and button markup will be changed to below:

```
<input type="button" id="btnBeforeOk" value="Ok" runat="server"  name="btnBeforeOk" style="width: 90%;" onserverclick="btnBeforeOk_ServerClick" />
```

and you can find below event in your code behind:

```
 protected void btnBeforeOk_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" OnClick="YourEvent" />
```

And do whatever you want to do in the code behind :

```
protected void YourEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //work
}
```