# opening code behind for input element?

Tags: html, asp.net, code-behind, runatserver, runat

everytime I try to open code behind for my

```html
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Upload" runat="server">
```

I get this

```html
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

        function Submit1_onclick() {

        }

// ]]>
    </script>
```

Can please anyone help me so I can go to code behind after double clicking ?

Comment: You might want to expand on your question, what do you want your script to do?

Comment: @AaronLavers that's the problem i don't want to write my code in the script, i'm working on uploading function for files, hope that well explained

Comment: use `onserverclick`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210119/how-to-create-onclick-event-in-cs-file-for-html-input-tag) is a related topic.